# Raspberry Pi 4 GPIOs are constantly on, even after restarting and cleaning up GPIOs

Tags: gpio, pi-4, electronics, relay

So, I got a Raspberry Pi 4 Model B, and I'm trying to make a project using relay boards.
Turns out, when I turn on my Pi, one of the pins is already active and the indicator turned on partially. I took a tester and kept on the GPIO pins just to find that they were active without any script activating them. Is my Pi defected or is it a built-in feature to keep the GPIOs on?

Please let me know.
Thanks!

[image: this]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you use a 5V Relay Module with the Pi?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/118116/can-you-use-a-5v-relay-module-with-the-pi)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [4 relay board weird behavior](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/92299/4-relay-board-weird-behavior)

Answer (score 0):

All the GPIO are pulled high or low at power-up.  GPIO 0-8 are pulled high to 3V3 the rest low to ground.

The pulls are quite weak (about 50k). If you need a different default you need to add external pulls.

See page 102 of [datasheet](https://datasheets.raspberrypi.com/bcm2835/bcm2835-peripherals.pdf) for the default pulls.

See [pinout](https://pinout.xyz/) for the mapping of pins to GPIO.

Comment: So should I transfer my GPIO pins that are present between 0-7 to a higher number like 17, 18, 19, etc?

Comment: That's one way of ensuring the GPIO you use are low by default.

Answer (score 0):

This has **NOTHING** to do with the Pi or GPIO.

These **lousy** modules are **unsuitable** for use with the Pi (they are poor for Arduino).
They can only be turned off by putting 5V on the inputs (or by setting GPIO to INPUT)!
Using with the PI risks damage!

**NOTE** there are hundreds of similar Questions by others who have problems with these.

See [Can you use a 5V Relay Module with the Pi?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/118117/8697)

PS the module DOES NOT indicate the state of the Pi GPIO. To reliably  check see [GPIOreadall](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/123749/8697)

Comment: But I have followed various tutorials, and I have literally implemented the exact same replica of the tutorial.
Here is one of the main ones I followed. [Link](https://www.electronicshub.org/control-a-relay-using-raspberry-pi/)

Comment: @bruhboi123345123: In that case, you should probably consult the author of the tutorial. The sad truth in today's marketplace is this: If you buy generic Chinese products without a data sheet or tech support, you will often be disappointed.

Comment: The linked project DOES NOT use the same crummy modules; it uses a transistor not an opto coupler to drive the relay.